# ubuntu apt-get for an offline installation

Tags: ubuntu, apt

We are using `apt-get install -d` do download all the required packeges from our installation in order not to need internet.

The thing is that apt-get isn't downloading what is already installed and it's a problem (even when starting on a "clean" machine)

Do I have an option to force download everything?

(or any other solution that doesn't involve mirroring the entire repo)

Comment: Try `apt-get install --reinstall -d ...`.

Comment: Finally got to test it. Worked! Thanks! If you want to write it as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Glad it helped; posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

Leverage `--reinstall`, which makes `apt-get`

> Re-Install packages that are already installed and at the newest version.

so, the complete command becomes: `apt-get install --reinstall -d $(your-packages)`.